# Importing a library from a git repository that's lacking a setup.py file

Tags: python, git, github, pip, setup-project

I'm trying to install the zetapy library corresponding to this repository https://github.com/JorritMontijn/zetapy. However, there is no setup.py file in the repository, so how would I approach this problem of installing a package from github without its corresponding setup.py file?

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own setup.py file, it's not difficult. Following [these instructions](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-create-a-python-library-7d5aea80cc3f) you can create your own library from the files they provide, and then just pip install it from a local directory.

Here's an example of a setup.py file:

```python
from setuptools import find_packages, setup
setup(
    name='mypythonlib',
    packages=find_packages(),
    version='0.1.0',
    description='My first Python library',
    author='Me',
    license='MIT',
)
```